# Can I manually upgrade from Windows 11 21H2 (non-compliant) to 22H2 using iso or MCT and keep program settings?

Tags: windows-11

I've been running Windows 11 (currently 21H2 Build 22000.1042), installing it when it first came out, even though I only had TPM 1.2 and a non-supported CPU. Everything has run fine and I've gotten all updates until now. I know 22H2 is a rolling release, and I guess it's possible that it still may appear in Windows update (it hasn't yet) but if it doesn't....   I've already tried the Update Assistant and it just flags that my computer doesn't meet the requirements.

I know I could do a clean install from the latest iso but then I'd have to reinstall all my programs again.

If I exported the current registry, and then imported it back after the update, would that work? Or, if anyone has a better idea for updating a non-compliant system without a clean install, please let me know.

Comment: “I only had TPM 1.2 and a non-supported CPU”, so how have you installed W11?

Comment: There are kinds of workarounds for installing W11 on older hardware

Comment: Use rufus to make a non compliant install usb drive, then run the setup exe on the thumb drive while in the OS, then it will allow an upgrade install.

Comment: https://www.ghacks.net/2022/03/04/rufus-3-18-adds-support-for-windows-11-inplace-upgrade-bypasses/

Comment: If by chance you get an error "We-couldn't-update-the-system-reserved-partition", which is a really small 16 MB partition (Microsoft Reserved Partition) then you can free some space on it by deleting some fonts from its Fonts folder.  The article is here  
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/-we-couldn-t-update-system-reserved-partition-error-installing-windows-10-46865f3f-37bb-4c51-c69f-07271b6672ac  
I managed by deleting just 8 of the largest fonts in the folder "EFI\Microsoft\Boot\Fonts"

Comment: I have the same problem. Windows 11 runs fine on an old 2014 laptop of mine (Atom-based, Intel Pentium N3540 Bay Train-M) with the UnsupportedCPU and such RegEdit trick (also no TPM and no SecureBoot). It's stuck at 21H2 but is regularly getting security updates. I am certain a new installation would just work the same way 21H1 did, but I would loose all settings and installed programs, so an upgrade would be the preferred option... So I'm looking for the same thing. OT: It's sad. Windows 10 was slower on this system, and I was surprised how well Windows 11 runs on this decade old laptop...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that it will work, based on the article that examined
this same question:
[Is Microsoft cracking down on Windows 11 updates for unsupported hardware?](https://www.zdnet.com/article/is-microsoft-cracking-down-on-windows-11-updates-for-unsupported-hardware/)

The author has tested, and 22H2 installs just as well as 22H1 on unsupported
hardware.

If Windows Update does not show you this update, the author has solved
the problem by downloading the ISO and doing a manual upgrade in place.

Reference : [Windows 11 In-place Upgrade](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/).